quiero ponerlo toda la pantalla y no puedo ¿como lo hago?
quiero ponerlo toda la pantalla y no puedo ¿como lo hago? no me deja y necesito para mi tarea, por favor ne pueden ayudar lo q no puedo es que el degradado no ocupa toda la pantalla  solo una parte y eso q ya puse  body  y html  el height al 100% por favor me pueden ayudar


* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange, orange, yellow, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#com {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 1920px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: arial black;
  font-size: 80px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
}
<div id="com">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recetas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<img src="images/seis.png">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>Somos guarana</h1>



asi me sale; pero no quiero que salga ese blanco
Título

Éste es mi código HTML (para ver el error hay que darle al botón de "Página Completa"):

Probaste algo como min-height: 100%? O min-height: 100vh??

Lo primero es una recomendación: quita todos esos <br>. Crear espacios usando <br> es una mala idea en general porque no tienes un control preciso sobre el tamaño que van a ocupar (a no ser que añadas más código CSS, pero eso es otra historia).
Ahora, si quieres que ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla, deberías poner un height de 100vh o 100svh (este último es mejor para dispositivos móviles). Yo personalmente organizaría todo en un contenedor (uso un <header> porque parece que es una cabecera, pero puedes usar el elemento que quieras) y le daría el height: 100svh a ese contenedor:
    header {
      min-height: 100vh; /* en caso de navegador no soporte svh */
      min-height: 100svh;
    }

Con eso vas a hacer que el contenedor ocupe el 100% del alto del viewport y, al ser un elemento de tipo bloque, también un 100% del ancho, ocupando todo el área de la pantalla visible.
Otra recomendación no relacionada viendo el código: no uses un tamaño absoluto para la imagen. Tal y como está ahora, le das un ancho fijo de 1920 píxeles, algo que puede funcionar en una pantalla grande, pero seguramente no sea el caso para todo el mundo dejando una imagen que no ocupa todo o, peor aún, que ocupa demasiado y crea scrolling. En lugar de eso, haz que la imagen tenga un valor relativo al contenedor y, para que no se distorsione, puedes ponerle un object-fit: cover u object-fit: contain para que se ajuste lo mejor posible al tamaño disponible.
Con esas tres cambios, el código quedaría así:


* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange, orange, yellow, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#com {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  /* mis cambios */
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-family: arial black;
  font-size: 80px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
}

/* mis cambios */
header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100svh;
}
<header>
  <div id="com">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Recetas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/600x400/">
  <h1>Somos guarana</h1>
</header>




Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.
Lista de cambios que hice y que sugiero:

Cambié la estructura html y la nomenclatura, para que tenga un mejor
seo, esté mejor estructurada, y sea más fácil de comprender

Considero importante utilizar box-sizing: border-box; para
normalizar los estilos, además de establecer los márgenes y padding
en 0 (cuando establecemos una medida en 0 no hace falta colocar
unidad), todo esto a todos los elementos.

Utilizar overflow: hidden; para evitar desbordamientos.

Le agregué un margen de 5px a la navegación, para que no esté pegada
al borde superior.

Eliminé el fondo transparente de los links de la navegación, ya que
es innecesario.

Cambié el ancho de la imagen para que se adapte a distintas
resoluciones, evitando el uso de medidas absolutas como lo son los px
para las imágenes.

Le agregué margin-left: 10px; al elemento <h1> para que no esté
pegado al borde izquierdo.

Hice que el elemento <header> ocupe el alto de toda la página.


Esta es mi primer respuesta en este sitio, espero haberlo hecho bien.


* {
    /*cambios*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange, orange, yellow, yellow);
    /*cambios*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*cambios*/
nav {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    /*cambios*/
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
  
ul,
ol {
    list-style: none;
}
  
.nav li a {
    /*cambios*/
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
  
.nav>li {
    float: left;
}
  
img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /*cambios*/
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
    font-family: arial black;
    font-size: 80px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    color: white;
    /*cambios*/
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/*cambios*/

header {
    height: 100vh;
}
<body>
    <!-- cambios -->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recetas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    

        <div id="contenido-principal">
            <img src="imagen.jpg">
            <h1>Somos guarana</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>



